# After logging in once, when you close and open the application, it does not log out. swiftui

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, appdelegate

```
import Firebase


@main
struct PaslaApp: App {
    
    //@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate: AppDelegate
    @StateObject var usersinfo=UsersInfoModel()
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
    
    init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
           HomeView()
        }
        .onChange(of: scenePhase) { newScenePhase in
            switch newScenePhase {
            case .active:
              print("App is active")
            case .inactive:
              print("App is inactive")
            case .background:
              print("App is in background")
            @unknown default:
              print("Oh - interesting: I received an unexpected new value.")
            }
          }
    }
}
```

I want to get data from firebase and start it on different screens according to availability, but I can't. I'm getting the error "please call firebaseapp.configure() before using firestore".
Please Help!

I need to write the code I wrote in appDelegate before swiftUI here.

var window: UIWindow?

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    
    let currentUser=Auth.auth().currentUser
    let firebaseDatabase=Firestore.firestore()
    var userTypeArray=[String]()
    var stadiumTypeArray=[String]()
    
    if currentUser != nil {
        firebaseDatabase.collection("Users").addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
            if error == nil {
                for document in snapshot!.documents{
                    if let userType=document.get("User") as? String{
                        userTypeArray.append(userType)
                        if userTypeArray.contains(currentUser!.uid) {
                            firebaseDatabase.collection("Users").whereField("User", isEqualTo: currentUser!.uid).addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
                                if error == nil {
                                    for document in snapshot!.documents {
                                        if let userName=document.get("Name") as? String{
                                            if userName == "" {
                                                let board=UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                                                let userInfo=board.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "userInfo")
                                                self.window?.rootViewController=userInfo
                                            } else {
                                                let board=UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                                                let userInfo=board.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "userProfile") as! UITabBarController
                                                self.window?.rootViewController=userInfo
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

return true
}

Comment: Does the `UsersInfoModel` initializer access Firebase?

Comment: I'm fetching data from firebase according to the functions I choose in that class. Of course if the user is logged in because the user is required by id.(Auth.auth().currentUser)

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. Consider that the `usersinfo` property is initialized **before** `PaslaApp.init` runs. So if the call to `UsersInfoModel` access Firebase, it does so **before** the app calls `FirebaseApp.configure`.

Comment: Never mind the init code I wrote, how can I change my start screen by making certain checks? These controls include fetching data from firebase. I can't do these in windowGroup